# insert number of hours mysql database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I wanna enter the number of hours of an aircraft, using Visual Basic, into a Mysql database.

For example:

- Aircraft X has 3158:25 hours

This means it has **3158 hours** and **25 minutes**.

In my database I've declared `Number of Hours` as `Time` (format).

The problem is that Visual Studio returns the following error:

> Incorrect time value: '3425:25' for column 'NbreHours' at row 1

Comment: This is outside the allowed range for the TIME datatype. Check the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html . You might be better working out the total number of minutes (or seconds, if you require that level of detail) and storing that as a number. You can always convert it back again when you want to display it.

Comment: Please consider to choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`3425:25` is not a correct `Time` format, change the format of your `NbreHours` column to `nvarchar(10)` and that will solve your issue.

---

The meaningful way to save a time in the `hh:mm` format is to calculate the total minutes of your record, and then to save it in the database as an `int`.

First sum the total minutes of your record:

```
string time = "3158:25:00";
double minutes= TimeSpan.Parse(time).TotalMinutes;
```

Then save the `minutes` variable in the database as an `int`.

Comment: if i do so, how to convert it to hours:minutes

Comment: I am not sure nvarchar is the best type to store a *number* of hours

Comment: @S.ElBahloul You mean when you pull the data from the database, how do you convert it back to `hours:minutes`?

Comment: @user3378165     i mean data entry: how can i enter the hours like that 3425:25 or 3425h25 and how to pull them from the database and convert them to do some addition task because the next flight i will just enter its duration and i will get the total hours

Comment: @GôTô  what do you suggest in return

Comment: I can't really help you because you didn't post any code snippet, I don't even know which language you use, post your code and I'll try to help you.

Comment: @S.ElBahloul it depends on the precision you want to keep, I would suggest an unsigned int as a number of minutes. Then do the conversion in the code